# Chrome me envía error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript

trato de convertir el contexto a JSON

```js
page('/', restrict, home);
page('/signin', signin);
page();

function restrict(ctx, next) {
  console.log('Restricting!');
  console.log('Context:' + JSON.stringify(ctx));
  console.log('window.user:' + window.user);
  if (!window.user) return page('/signin');
  next();
}

function home() {
  console.log('estoy navegando al home');
  $('.app-container').html(hometemplate);
}

function signin() {
  $('.app-container').html(signintemplate);
  $('.Signin-button').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $('.Signin-name-input')[0].value;
    if (!username) return alert('Ingrese un nombre valido!');
    window.user = {
      username: username
    };
    page('/');
  });
}

page({
  hasbang: true
});
```

pero me sale el error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se puede transformar un objeto con ciclos a JSON porque entra en un bucle infinito:

```js
const obj1= {
  atributo1: 'hola'
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1));
obj1.atributo2=obj1; //se apunta a si mismo

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

El motivo es que esto generaría un JSON como:

```
{
  "atributo1":"hola"
  "atributo2": {
    "atributo1":"hola"
    "atributo2": {
      "atributo1":"hola"
      "atributo2": {
        "atributo1":"hola"
        "atributo2": {
         ... hasta el infinito y más allá

}
```

Comment: y en mi caso como puedo hacer?

Comment: Si simplemente quieres mostrar en consola información del contexto, elije qué propiedades quieres mostrar e ignora las demás.

Comment: okey la cosa es que no se como hacerlo, disculpa la ignorancia

Comment: Bueno, no sé que atributos tiene tu objeto ctx, pero puedes hacer un `console.log(ctx)` o un `console.log(ctx,atributo1, ctx.atributo2)`

Comment: bro utilice console.log(ctx) y funciono gracias